# Roundcube is giving server error with no logs. Strange AJAX response

Tags: php, apache, roundcube

After an apache2 and php update, roundcube started to give Server Error dialogs. I checked the ajax responses and the data is received but with strange characters in the end.

```
{"action":"refresh","unlock":"loading1415016032431","exec":"this.set_unread_count(\"INBOX\",0,true,\"\");\n"}����������������
```

What could it mean?

Versions:
Roundcube 0.9.5

apache 2.2.22

php 5.3.10

Ubuntu 12.04

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, all I had to do was to enable `expires` apache2 module.